# How to save and resume ScrollPosition

Tags: android, scrollview

I need help saving my scrollview's position when resuming the activity.
I have a long scrollview containing some buttons. When I click on those buttons, new activities are opened. When I resume the scrollview's activity, the scrollview starts from the top and the user has to scroll again. This is pretty annoying.

How can i save the scrollview position?

I found this, but the line: `Util.Log("X:" + scrollX + " Y:" + scrollY);` doesn't work:

```
//  two static variable,
public static int scrollX = 0;
public static int scrollY = -1;

//update & save their value on onPause & onResume.
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
  super.onPause();
  scrollX = scrollView.getScrollX();
  scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
}
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
  Util.Log("X:" + scrollX + " Y:" + scrollY);
  super.onResume();
  //this is important. scrollTo doesn't work in main thread.
  scrollView.post(new Runnable()
{
@Override
public void run()
{
  scrollView.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
}
});
}
```

Thank you for your help! :D

EDIT:

If i remove the line, I'll get this error:

```
 01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): Process: com.example.appquiz, PID: 1967
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.appquiz/com.example.appquiz.Categories}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2837)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.example.appquiz.Categories.onResume(Categories.java:82)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5319)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2798)
01-01 17:29:11.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     ... 12 more
```

My entire code:

```
public static int scrollX = 0;
public static int scrollY = -1;
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Scrollview);

//blabla

onCreate //...

@Override
protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    scrollX = scrollView.getScrollX();
    scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
    super.onPause();
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    scrollView.post(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     public void run(){
       scrollView.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);}});}
```

Comment: How exactly that line doesn't work? Seems legit to me

Comment: Util.Log gives me an error, i don't know how to fix it. If i try somehow to change that line it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please explain me what "Util.Log("X:" + scrollX + " Y:" + scrollY);" is and how to use it?

Comment: That's something for logging what's happening. You can safely remove that line

Comment: i receive an error :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this code to the end of your inflateView method and please make sure that R.id.Scrollview is the right Id

```
scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Scrollview);
```

By the way, you should not use post method to do this. The best way to scroll the view is to do the following:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = scrollView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

If that does not help please tell us what line is this:(com.example.appquiz.Categories.onResume(Categories.java:82))

Comment: i add this in onActivityCreated in Fragment but not work ??? may be due to replacefragment ..how can i save state

Comment: what exactly isn't working? Please, consider creating a new question with more detailed information

Answer (score 0):

Util.Log("X:" + scrollX + " Y:" + scrollY); remove this code dude this is just logging code and nothing to do with functionality

Comment: Probably your scroll view is null how did u restore this value

Comment: ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Scrollview); put this line in the oncreate function, is this where it is?

Comment: No, it isn't. Thank you, i'll try.